# google font doesn't work

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

I am trying to add a google font as per instructions, and it works in testing files, but fails to load on a production site.

http://www.bleskuborka.ru/services/

The headings УБОРКА ОФИСА, УБОРКА КВАРТИРЫ etc. are supposed to be rendered with Roboto Condensed.

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The font is linked to page. The font-family is specified:

```
.serv-heading {
font-family: 'Roboto-Condensed', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Still, something is missing.

I first thought that this might be due to the cyrillic characters but I tried renaming the headings into English, and it didn't work out.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried with Roboto Condensed (space instead of a dash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Roboto Condensed`. With space instead of dash.

```
.serv-heading {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: yep. Absolutely not smart of me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Roboto Condensed instead of Roboto-Condensed and it will work fine:

```
.serv-heading {
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Also note to use https with Google Font links, it will avoid some issues if one day you work on a https website!